# Finding $i^{i^i}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Express $i^{i^i}$ in the form $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are real.

From euler's formula, I get $\ln i=i\pi/2$, which leads to $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$.

Therefore, $\ln i^{i^i}=i^i\ln i=i\pi e^{-\pi/2}/2,i^{i^i}=e^{i\pi e^{-\pi/2}/2}$, but I don't know how to deal with this.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The formula $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$ might be of use.

Comment: Isn't it undefined because of branching?